# r - find equal elements in list based on multiple data.frame columns and delete them

Tags: r, list, dataframe, duplicates, multiple-columns

Let's suppose I have the following `data.frames` that form my list:

```
df_1 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,2,5,6), y = c(20,20,21,24,55), z = rnorm(5))
df_2 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,2,5,6), y = c(20,20,21,24,55), z = rnorm(5))

df_3 = data.frame(x = c(3,3,5,6), y = c(20,20,21,24), z = rnorm(4))
df_4 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,2), y = c(20,20,21), z = rnorm(3))
df_5 = data.frame(x = c(2,2,5,6), y = c(19,20,21,40), z = rnorm(4))

df_6 = data.frame(x = c(1,5,6), y = c(20,20,24), z = rnorm(3))
df_7 = data.frame(x = c(1,5,6), y = c(20,20,24), z = rnorm(3))
df_8 = data.frame(x = c(1,5,6), y = c(20,20,24), z = rnorm(3))

df_lst = list(df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5, df_6, df_7, df_8)
```

As you see `df_1` and `df_2` have identical `x` and `y` columns and the same applies to `df_6`, `df_7` and `df_8`.

How can I remove the duplicated `data.frames` based on columns `x` and `y`?

I do not care which `df` is removed, i.e. it could be either `df_1` OR `df_2` and `df_6` AND `df_7`, OR `df_6` AND `df_8`, OR `df_7` AND `df_8`.

My real list has thousands of `data.frames`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way...

```
df_lst[!duplicated(lapply(df_lst, function(df) df[,c("x","y")]))]

[[1]]
  x  y          z
1 1 20 -0.8043316
2 2 20 -1.0565257
3 2 21 -1.0353958
4 5 24 -1.1855604
5 6 55 -0.5004395

[[2]]
  x  y          z
1 3 20  0.3509210
2 3 20  0.8633185
3 5 21 -0.4789113
4 6 24 -1.1884792

[[3]]
  x  y           z
1 1 20 -0.26856637
2 2 20 -0.08022106
3 2 21 -0.12323569

[[4]]
  x  y           z
1 2 19 -0.09943981
2 2 20 -0.83475398
3 5 21  1.85777954
4 6 40 -0.49839702

[[5]]
  x  y          z
1 1 20 -1.2700546
2 5 20 -0.9369437
3 6 24  0.5334392
```

First it forms a dummy list including just columns `x` and `y` of each dataframe, works out the duplicates using that list, and then removes the corresponding elements from the original list (keeping the first occurrence of each).

Comment: can drop the `,` from `df[,c("x","y")]`

Comment: @snoram Yes, you get the same result, but it is noticeably quicker with the comma - on my machine `microbenchmark` shows at least 30% faster, which is probably significant if the OP has a very long list.

Comment: A slightly shorter variation is `df_lst[!duplicated(lapply(df_lst, "[", c("x", "y")))]`